# icu RegexMatcher memory not freed

Tags: c++, regex, icu

Memory is not being released when I use RegexMatcher (from icu api).
Memory is not getting freed after I have done a reset, each reset causes more memory to be lost (inputBuffer is a UnicodeString).

It seems that just creating a new RegexMatcher object and then deleting it leaks memory...

Any ideas what I'm missing please?

```
UErrorCode matcherStatus = U_ZERO_ERROR;
RegexMatcher * lastWordMatcher = new RegexMatcher(".*(^|\\p{Z})(\\S+)$", UREGEX_ERROR_ON_UNKNOWN_ESCAPES | UREGEX_UWORD, matcherStatus);

UnicodeString lastWord;

lastWordMatcher->reset(inputBuffer);
if (lastWordMatcher->find(matcherStatus))
{
    lastWord = lastWordMatcher->group(2, matcherStatus);
}
delete lastWordFinder;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hidden inside icu docs is this comment

> When an application is terminating, it may optionally call the function u_cleanup(void) , which will free any heap storage that has been allocated and held by the ICU library. The main benefit of u_cleanup() occurs when using memory leak checking tools while debugging or testing an application. Without u_cleanup(), memory being held by the ICU library will be reported as leaks.